# Factory with $3$ production lines

Tags: probability

A factory has $3$ production lines $A, B$ and $C$ contributing $20$%, $30$% and $50$%, respectively, to its total output. The percentages of substandard items produced by lines $A, B$ and $C$ are $10, 5$, and $2$, respectively.

a) If an item is chosen at random from the total output, what is the probability that it will be a substandard item?

b) Suppose that an item chosen at random from the total output is found to be substandard. What is the probability that it is from line $A$ ?

Comment: I could give you the answer straight away but you'll miss out on learning and understanding the most fundamental problem in probability - Bayes theorem. I strongly suggest reading that theorem and trying to answer it.  If you're not able to,  just comment below and I'll answer the question :)

Comment: HInt. Work out the number of substandard items from each line assuming there are 1000 items in total. Then you might see what fractions produce the answers to your questions. (This is really Bayes' theorem, without needing to know the theorem explicitly.)

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing this is just to consider a representative sample.  Let's choose $200$ items, because this will yield round numbers.

Of those $200$ items, Line A produces $40$ of them, of which $10$ percent, or $4$, are faulty.

Line B produces $60$ of them, of which how many are faulty?

And finally, Line C produces $100$ of them, of which how many are faulty?

Now, just add up the faulty items out of $200$ to answer (a).  (Remember that it's out of $200$, not $100$.)  For (b), consider the faulty items only: How many of them were from Line A?

Answer (score 0):

See [Bayes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem)

**Hint:**

Let $H$ be the event the item is substandard, and $H^{c}$ the event that the item is ok

$$P(A)=0.2,P(B)=0.3,P(C)=0.5$$

For $a)$ you need to find $P(H)$

For $b)$ you need to find  $P(A|H)$