# Probability that an item is faulty

Tags: probability

A company has 3 factories A, B, and C, which manufacture television sets. The probability
that a set made in A is faulty is 0.02, and the corresponding probabilities for B and C are
0.03 and 0.05 respectively. If A, B, and C produce respectively 50%, 30%, and 20% of total
output, what is the probability that a set manufactured by the company is faulty?(II)What
proportion of faulty sets is produced by each factory?

---

My approach:
$$P(\text{faulty})=\frac{50}{100}\cdot(0.02)+ \frac{30}{100}\cdot(0.03)+ \frac{20}{100}\cdot(0.05)  =0.01+0.009+0.01  
  =0.029$$
And the proportion of share of faulty sets will be 0.01, 0.009 and 0.01.
I solved this using general logic that 50% is produced from A of which 0.02 can be faulty and so on. What is this approach called in probability terms and is my approach correct? [This is the same question as mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1646302/factory-with-3-production-lines) But I needed to clarify if my approach is correct .

Comment: For (II) the proportions of faulty sets produced by each factory should probably add up to $1$

Comment: @Henry: right. Thanks